# Eclipse new jsp file is Not Found

Tags: eclipse, file, jsp, new-operator

The Eclipse IDE project displays all the jsp files in the correct location and correct URL.  The application works with the existing old files.  However, when a new file is created or even copied from an existing file, the new file displays a 'Not Found' message on the screen.

I have tried the following:

- Restarting the server
- Refreshing the project, the folder, and the file using F5.
- 'Close Project' and reopening the project
- Exporting war file and importing war file under a new project name

The application comes up but the new files display 'Not Found'.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right URL, then?

Comment: I should have right URL.  To make this very simple, within Eclipse, I copied file.jsp and pasted file2 in same location.  In the Project Explorer, the files are next to each other and no code was changed.  file2.jsp is still not visible in URL.